# Conversion: np.array of indices to np.array of corresponding dict entries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of indices in **Python 2.7** that correspond to a value in a dictionary. So I want to create a numpy array of the corresponding values from the dictionary. The code might be clear immediately:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.array([(0, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0)], dtype=[('A', int), ('B', int)])
d = {(0, 1): 10,
     (2, 0): 9}
values = d[(indices['A'], indices['B'])]
```

The call in the last line is not hashable (I tried to find a [way to make a np.array hashable](http://machineawakening.blogspot.ch/2011/03/making-numpy-ndarrays-hashable.html) but it did not work):

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I could substitute this by a loop but this takes ages to write the variable `values`:

```
np.array([d[(indices[i]['A'], indices[i]['B'])] for i in range(len(indices))])
```

Or is there any alternative for dict to make such task pythonic, i.e. faster? The variable `indices` can not be changed but I can change the type of `dict`.

#### Edit

The actual index array contains also other entries. That is why I wrote the calls so complicated:

```
indices = np.array([(0, 1, 's'), (2, 0, 's'), (2, 0, 't')],
                   dtype=[('A', int), ('B', int), ('C', str)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use a list comprehension for this (it would be a bit faster than a normal `for` loop method). Example -

```
values = [d[tuple(a)] for a in indices]
```

Please note, I am using `d` instead of `dict`, since it would not be recommended to use `dict` as a variable name, as that would shadow the built-in type `dict`.

Demo -

```
In [73]: import numpy as np

In [74]: indices = np.array([(0, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0)], dtype=[('A', int), ('B', int)])

In [76]: d = {(0, 1): 10,
   ....:  (2, 0): 9}

In [78]: values = [d[tuple(a)] for a in indices]

In [79]: values
Out[79]: [10, 9, 9]
```

---

A faster method for larger arrays would be to use [`np.vectorize()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to vectorize the `dict.get()` method and then apply that on the `indices` array. Example -

```
vecdget = np.vectorize(lambda x: d.get(tuple(x)))
vecdget(indices)
```

Demo with timing results -

```
In [88]: vecdget = np.vectorize(lambda x: d.get(tuple(x)))

In [89]: vecdget(indices)
Out[89]: array([10,  9,  9])

In [98]: indices = np.array([(0, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0)] * 100, dtype=[('A', int), ('B', int)])

In [99]: %timeit [d[tuple(a)] for a in indices]
100 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit vecdget(indices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 341 µs per loop
```

Timing test for the new method suggested by @hpaulj in the comments - `[d.get(x.item()) for x in indices]` -

```
In [114]: %timeit [d.get(x.item()) for x in indices]
1000 loops, best of 3: 417 µs per loop

In [115]: %timeit vecdget(indices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 331 µs per loop

In [116]: %timeit [d.get(x.item()) for x in indices]
1000 loops, best of 3: 354 µs per loop

In [117]: %timeit vecdget(indices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 262 µs per loop
```

Comment: Sorry, was it not clear enough? I am looking for a faster one. Each round takes 3s in my case and it runs about 1k times.

Comment: I doubt if there would be any faster method, if one comes, I will delete this one.

Comment: @strpeter Updated the answer with a bit more faster method, try that out.

Comment: `[d.get(x.item()) for x in indices]`is nearly as fast as your `vecdget`.  `tuple(x)` is relatively slow.

Comment: True, but the vectorized function is still 40-60 microseconds faster on my system. I will add the timing test on my comp to the answer as well. But yes, the `tuple()` method really is very slow, wonder why.

Comment: `x.tolist()` is also quite a bit better than `tuple(x)`.  `tolist` and `item` are the array's own methods.  `tuple()` adds atleast one layer of Python processing, maybe more.

Comment: The function `np.vectorize` gave a speed up of a factor 100 for my rather complex code with respect to the loop-filled list! Thank you.

Comment: I generalized @AnandSKumar's code `vecdget = np.vectorize(lambda A, B: delays_phase.get(tuple((A, B))); vecdget(indices['A'], indices['B'])`. This works fine.